# Android dialog colors

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to change the title area background color of Dialogs in android? For example, in the image below, I am able to change the color of the 'Default Body' background, but not the 'Default Title' background. Is there any way to do this without creating a custom dialog?

[image]

Comment: `Without creating a custom dialog..` do you mean without creating an xml file that can be set as Dialog's view?

Comment: No, I'm actually already doing that. I meant I don't really want to create an entirely custom dialog, which is what seems to be the go to solution in the places I've looked for answers. I'm able to change the color of the portion of the Dialog that is being drawn from my xml file, but not the 'title' area.

Comment: If you are doing that, then do you have the `TextView` which for the Title? If yes, then you can reference it and change its color, right?

Comment: I am using the setTitle(String) method, not a textview. Maybe I could pass a textview to that method, I'll try that.

Comment: Nope, I still have a white background in the title area, even with the background of the textview being black.

Answer (score 1):

there is lib that handle changing the dialog title and more ,

take look there

https://github.com/danoz73/QustomDialog